# Composing Roles into a Moose class not working

Tags: perl, oop, moose

Aloha!

I have a role that I'm busy defining in a Moose class called Authable that is essentially composed into any class that might potentially require some form of authentication in the future; it's a rather simple role, here's the entirety:

```
package Trello::API::Roles::Authable;

use Moose::Role;

#authentication information
has key => (
    is => "rw",
    isa => "Str",
);

has token => (
    is => "rw",
    isa => "Str",
);

1;
```

For whatever reason, when I attempt to compose it into a class using multiple different statements, i.e.,
    with "Trello::API::Roles::Authable";
or
    with "Roles::Authable";

I consistently get this same error message: `You can only consume roles, Roles::Authable is not a Moose role.`

Any idea why this might be happening?

Edit!

Just a side note, I checked the actual source for Moose::Role, and saw this bit:

```
    unless ($meta && $meta->isa('Moose::Meta::Role') ) {
        require Moose;
        Moose->throw_error( "You can only consume roles, "
                . $role->[0]
                . " is not a Moose role" );
    }
```

This seems to be where the error is occuring, so it almost seems that for some reason, the role I'm implementing isn't stating that it's a role in the metaclass. Though I could be mistaken! Any help would be appreciated.

Another convenient EDIT!

Bonus: Code context wherein the with routine is called.

```
package Trello::API::Resource;

use Moose;
use URI::Escape;
use LWP::UserAgent;


with 'Roles::Authable';
```

which when I do this, it intelligently knows to try and consume Roles/Authable.pm but for whatever reason, it just fails to function!

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple different statements?" Are you doing `with 'Trello::API::Roles::Authable'` or `with 'Roles::Authable';`? Because you don't appear to have a role with the latter name.

Comment: [Are you using `Moose` or `Any::Moose`?](http://blogs.perl.org/users/sawyer_x/2012/05/priorities-when-using-anymoose-and-what-mouse-people-should-do.html)

Comment: What I mean is I've tried multiple different variations; at this point, the file trying to consume the role is Trello::API::Resource, so it seems to recognize Roles::Authable as Trello::API::Roles::Authable, and attempt to consume that module. At this point, it isn't going to recognize where the modules are as I haven't put them into the actual module directory strucutre; I could always modify @INC but at this point I'm just curious why the role can't be consumed as such.

Comment: Do you declare the code in multiple files or in just one file? In what order are your classes defined?

Comment: You really should be doing `with "Trello::API::Roles::Authable"`, and for that to work you should have either already `require`d Trello::API::Roles::Authable, or T::A::R::Authable should be defined in `lib/Trello/API/Roles/Authable.pm`. Moose doesn't do magic with package names in this context; it doesn't know that when you say `with "Roles::Authable"`, you really mean `with "Trello::API::Roles::Authable"` - how could it?

So, either put your packages in appropriately named files so Moose can find them, or `require` whatever weird files need requiring before attempting to compose anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to agree with Piers that technically, you really should be calling it as `with 'Trello::API::Roles::Authable'`.

So, you're asking for something that I don't find to be implemented in basic Moose. 
I have used the ideas of generic namespace pools before. They are sort of universal namespaces to which you can offer your 
semi-anonymous services--without the lock-in of a fixed namespace. I refined my basic idea of the namespace pool with Moose (really *`MOP`*) support.

In the Wild West days of Perl, all you would have to do is assign one stash to the symbol for the other, like so:

```
{   no strict 'refs'; 
    *{$short_pkg_name.'::'} = \*{$full_pkg_name.'::'};
};
```

And, those two packages were exactly the same things!

But now, we guard our data with lexicals a bit more. And because Class::MOP jealously guards its meta objects in a lexical hash, you have to add something else:

```
Class::MOP::store_metaclass_by_name( 
       $short_pkg_name
     , Class::MOP::get_metaclass_by_name( $full_pkg_name )
     );
```

Now they are the exact same thing to Perl and to MOP.

Thus you can create packages that are simply a namespace repository for other packages
-- *Now with `MOP` support!*

```
package Namespace::Pool;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Params::Util qw<_POSINT>;

sub import { 
    shift; # It's just me.
    my $full_pkg_name = caller();
    Carp::croak( "'$full_pkg_name' is short enough!" ) 
        unless my $pool_name 
            = shift // [ split /::/, $full_pkg_name ]->[-2]
            ;
    Carp::croak( "'::$pool_name\::' not found in '$full_pkg_name'" ) 
        unless (  _POSINT( my $pos = rindex( $full_pkg_name, "::$pool_name\::" ))
               or my $is_short = _POSINT( index( $pool_name, '::' ))
               ); 
    my $short_pkg_name 
        = $is_short ? $poll_name 
        :             substr( $full_pkg_name, $pos + 2 )
        ;
    {   no strict 'refs'; 
        if ( %{$short_pkg_name.'::'} ) { 
            Carp::croak( "You have already defined $short_pkg_name!" );
        }
        *{$short_pkg_name.'::'} = \*{$full_pkg_name.'::'};
    };

    if ( my $meta = Class::MOP::get_metaclass_by_name( $full_pkg_name )) { 
        Class::MOP::store_metaclass_by_name( $short_pkg_name, $meta );
    }
    return;
}
```

Thus in your Role package you can do the following:

```
package Trello::API::Roles::Authable;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose::Role;
use Namespace::Pool 'Roles';
...
```

And know that it will be available from the namespace of 'Roles'.

Comment: I appreciate it greatly. I ended up just using the fully qualified name of the Role after I realized that it was working, so, problem was solved, but your explanation was extremely in depth and provided a good starting ground for achieving what I was attempting to do, so thank you so much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'd simply accidentally named my role 'Test', but there was already an installed module on my system called 'Test' and so Moose thought I wanted to consume that module rather than the new Moose role I'd created. Once I renamed by role to 'Testable' it all worked fine.